# How to create different aliases by doing different queries in the same column in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I have a table in MySQL where I store indexes, and I need to count a column of indices by bringing an alias for each count.

I tried the following code but it does not work, and as I am new to Laravel, I'm not sure how I can build this query

```
$data = Baralho::select(
        DB::raw("YEAR(data_entrada) as ano"),
        DB::raw("count(id_situacao) as inseridos, id_situacao"),
        DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 2) as presos"),
        DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 3) as mortos"),
        DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 4) as retirados")
    )->groupBy("ano")->get();
    $geral[] = ['Ano', 'Inseridos', 'Presos', 'Mortos', 'Retirados'];
    //$anos = $data->pluck('ano');
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $geral[++$key] = [$value->ano, $value->inseridos, $value->presos, $value->mortos, $value->retirados ];
    }
    dd($geral);
```

I need it to count the indexes and return a result for each alias, for example, if in the column `id_situacao` the index is `2` it counts all 2 indexes and brings me the result with the alias `presos` so that I can insert those results in my array `$geral[]`

[dd($geral) Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKVha.png)

Edit:
I tried with the following code:

```
$data = DB::select(
            DB::raw('(SELECT YEAR(data_entrada) as ano FROM baralho)'),
            DB::raw('(SELECT count(id_situacao) as inseridos FROM baralho)'),
            DB::raw('(SELECT count(id_situacao) as presos FROM baralho WHERE id_situacao = 2)'),
            DB::raw('(SELECT count(id_situacao) as mortos FROM baralho WHERE id_situacao = 3)'),
            DB::raw('(SELECT count(id_situacao) as retirados FROM baralho WHERE id_situacao = 4)')
        )->groupBy('ano')->get();;
        $geral[] = ['Ano', 'Inseridos', 'Presos', 'Mortos', 'Retirados'];
        //$anos = $data->pluck('ano');
        //dd($anos);
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $geral[++$key] = [$value->ano, $value->inseridos, $value->presos, $value->mortos, $value->retirados];
            //dd($value);
        }
        dd($geral);
```

but I received the error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type
>   array, object given, called in
>   /home/.../.../...com/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
>   on line 328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve my problem in the following way:

```
$data = Baralho::select(
            DB::raw("YEAR(data_entrada) as ano"),
            DB::raw("count(id_situacao) as inseridos, id_situacao"),
            DB::raw("count(case when id_situacao = 2 then 1 end) as presos"),
            DB::raw("count(case when id_situacao = 3 then 1 end) as mortos"),
            DB::raw("count(case when id_situacao = 4 then 1 end) as retirados")
        )->groupBy("ano")->get();
        $geral[] = ["Ano", "Inseridos", "Presos", "Mortos", "Retirados"];
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $geral[++$key] = [$value->ano, $value->inseridos, $value->presos, $value->mortos, $value->retirados ];
        }
```

Only with the `CASE` clause I was able to count the `id_situacao` fields by grouping by id and returning an alias for each type

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation was not clear to me, but I think I understand what you want. Try this:

```
$data = Baralho::select(
    DB::raw("YEAR(data_entrada) as ano"),
    DB::raw("count(id_situacao) as inseridos, id_situacao"),
    DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 2) as presos"),
    DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 3) as mortos"),
    DB::raw("count(id_situacao = 4) as retirados")
)->groupBy("ano")->get();

$geral = [];
//$anos = $data->pluck('ano');
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $geral[++$key] = ['Ano' => $value->ano, 'Inseridos' => $value->inseridos, 'Presos' => $value->presos, 'Mortos' => $value->mortos, 'Retirados' => $value->retirados ];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention and willingness to help, but `count(id_situacao =?)` does not work, I ended up solving using `CASE`